# Suggested RAM for inspiron 1720

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-inspiron

I have a inspiron 1720 with 2gb ram, what kind of ram should I buy, I want to get 4gb.

i'm running windows 7 on it.

Do I have to buy 4gb or should there be empty slots?

Any links would be appreciated, I want to get an idea of the $ involved to see if its worth it.

I am hoping it will make it substantially faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all relevant info at [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Inspiron%201720).

Their [scanner tool](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/index.aspx) will show you what memory you are currently using.

Your system has two slots which can only accept up to 2GB modules.  They offer a <strike>pair of</strike> 2GB module for $57 which will give you 4GB for $114.

Answer (score 1):

The [Inspiron 1720](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=inspiron+1720) has two (2) memory slots, one is accessed from underneath the keyboard and the other from the bottom of the computer.

Since you already have 2 gigs of RAM, the configuration is mostly likely 2x1GB. In other words, both of your memory slots are most likely already filled with 1GB memory modules.

This means you'll [most likely] have to replace both 1GB memory modules (2x1GB) with 2GB memory modules (2x2GB): [Dell 2GB Module for Dell Inspiron 1720 Laptops](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Memory_Upgrades/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=A1213046).

**note**: as noted in the comments, verify your memory configuration before buying new RAM.

For reference, here is the [Dell Inspiron 1720 User Manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins1720/en/om_en/pdf/DT5494MR.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: ... but @sososo will want to verify that they've got 2 memory modules already (2x1gb); it's possible (tho unlikely) they've got 1x2gb module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 5GB in my Inspiron 1720 using both a 4GB and a 1GB module.  I'll be replacing the 1GB with a 2GB to max out this system at it's limit of 6GB.

Please note that this is more of an undocumented limit above and beyond the 4GB which Dell lists, but I can attest to the fact that it works with more than 4GB!

I got the inspiration to upgrade mine here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-inspiron-dell-studio/305464-inspiron-1720-6gb-ram-tested-7.html

Answer (score 0):

That model of laptop can support 2 SODIMM memory modules of 2gb each of DDR2 667MHZ.

Taken from documentation found [here.](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins1720/en/om_en/html/specs.htm#wp1102222)